# Bluetooth speaker connects but can't be selected

Tags: bluetooth

I've followed the arch wiki instructions for using a bluetooth speaker, and was able to pair and connect. Still, only my internal speaker is used, and I see no option in pavucontrol. What should I do? Using Arch.

```
~ % pactl list short|grep bluetooth
7       module-bluetooth-policy
8       module-bluetooth-discover
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `pactl list short | grep bluetooth`  Thanks

Comment: @Jeremy31, done.

Comment: `pactl list cards` result after pairing with the speaker.  Does the speaker happen to be a UE Boom?